# SQL Server str rounding error = '******'

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an odd sql server behaviour I couldn't resolve or find an answer to, but I found out the answer so am posting here as a self-answer

```
select
str(value,6,2)
from a
```

results in value:

```
"******"
```

Obviously I am aware of the issues with rounding numeric values, but I was receiving an error value = "******" which I struggled to find documentation for resolution

Answer (score 0):

the value in question was:

```
'999.995'
```

the character and decimal place parameters were causing an interesting error

str(value,6,2)

specifies 6 characters, with 2 decimal places, but when '999.995' is rounded it results in:

```
'1000.00'
```

which has 7 characers and 2 decimal places, which contradicts the earlier request for 6 characters, and produces the error:

```
"******"
```

This was fairly complicated to isolate in the script, and I thought it would be useful to share here